# How can I add page background color of pdf using iText in java

Tags: java, itextpdf

I am new to `iText` pdf library. Can any one guide me how to add background color to entire ***page*** (not for chunk or paragraph) using iText `pdf` in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the job:

```
Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(216, 720);
pageSize.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xDE));
Document document = new Document(pageSize);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.But error shows as color can not converted to base color at line " pageSize.setBackgroundColor(new java.awt.Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xDE)); "

Comment: @Arunjk wich version of Itext do you use? have you imported the correct objects?

Comment: ooops my mistake. i did not imported. Could you please tell me how to add background color to alternate pages? I tried but couldn't get through. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Arunjk Sorry can't get you. Do you want to have e.g. first page yellow. second page red and so on?

Comment: I want only first two pages in blue color and rest of pages in white color.

Comment: In this case you have to use PageEvents. Look [here](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/adding-page-events-to-pdfwriter-itext-5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(400, 720); 
pageSize.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.YELLOW);
Document document = new Document(pageSize);
```

Comment: This nearly is a copy of the accepted answer, isn't it?